# Which option to say "in the entire country" is correct?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

How do I say *in the entire country of France*?

- In all of France
- In whole France
- In the whole France

Comment: Either in "*In all of France*", "*In all France*", "*In the whole of France*", or "*In the whole country*" (without naming France). If you want the reasoning behind these choices, or just more information, you should ask on our sister site, [ELL.se].

Comment: Let's just say it's more on-topic on ELL. EL&U is more focused on topics relevant to native speakers (or people with a native level of fluency), linguists, and etymologists, where ELL is focused on helping people *learn* to use English effectively.

Comment: Why not omit all of them? 'In France they speak French', can have the  same meaning as 'In all of France they speak French'.

Comment: @Christopher Emphasis.

Comment: @Dan Bron Just pointing out a less wordy option can still be concise.

Comment: In the whole of France. It depends on the context though.

Comment: This needs more context. Are you talking about the entire land area of France, or the entire populace of France?

Comment: entire land area of France was what I was thinking

Comment: Isn't "in the entire France" OK ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the geographic boundaries of a nation, these two are valid options:

- This is the best restaurant in all of France.
- This is the best restaurant in the whole of France.

You need the definite article when you use "whole of."

Of those two, I would probably use *all of* instead of the *the whole of* most of the time. The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20all%20of%20France%2C%20in%20the%20whole%20of%20France&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) on this is quite interesting; it indicates "all of" is on the rise, while "the whole of" is on the decline. (However, that doesn't mean "the whole of" is wrong or inappropriate.)

You can also change the preposition to *throughout*, and the "all of" is implied:

- This is the best restaurant throughout France.

Then again, you can use "in" to say the same thing:

- This is the best restaurant in France.

The qualifiers "in all of" and "in the whole of" aren't really necessary when dealing with superlatives. However, there are times when you want to emphasize that are talking about all of something in an entire country, and not just a subset:

- There are 56 nuclear power plants in all of France.

Answer (score -2):

'The French' would be my response. I opine you use the general reference for the populace of the entity you are referring to.

Comment: Nope. "The French" are a people; "France" is a country. You can have a tree which is the tallest in all of France, but doesn't have a French passport.

Comment: @DanBron, _but doesn't have a French passport._ What do you mean?

Comment: @XPMai It was a funny way to say the tree is not a citizen of France.  The tree is *not* included in "The French". So Ibrahim's answer is incorrect.